# Solving for a Limit Given a Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$
>   \text{Given}\; 
>   \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x)-4}{x-1} = 10, 
>   \;\text{evaluate}\;
>   \lim_{x \to 1} f(x)
> $$

I'm wondering if anyone can give me some tips on how to approach this problem. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: HINT: $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: @adam19325 Just for future reference, please include _all_ your working next time in your question, even if you haven't been able to do much, only so that we can see where a problem may lie and better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears that you're doing basic calculus, I'll put my answer in terms of that.

The definition for the slope of a tangent line on a curve using limits is as follows

> $$ 
>   \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = m
> $$

Now let's look at what they give you,

> $$ 
>   \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x)-4}{x-1} = 10
> $$

Finally, let's look at what they ask of you,

> $$ 
>   \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = ?
> $$

If you look at the definition and what they've given you, you'll see that they have given you $f(1)$. Since the function is continuous at $x=1$,

$$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(1)$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 4$$

Always remember to look for any correlation between your equations and your problem if you ever get stuck.

Comment: Explained very well for the OPs level of understanding. +1

Comment: where is it given that $f$ is continuous and also that $f(1) = 4$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I didn't say that $f$ was continuous, I said that $f$ was continuous at $x=1$. This is given by the presence of a defined slope at $x=1$, which could not exist if $f$ was not continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is continuous at $x = 1$? Also where is it provided that $f(1) = 4$? A proper answer is the one I have provided.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh "This is given by the presence of a defined slope at $x=1$, which could not exist if $f$ was not continuous at $x=1$." $f(1)$ is provided by correlating the definition with the provided equation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh This was just shorthand for me saying that the limits approached the same value from the left and right, the value for $f(1)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The only proper answer is the one that makes the most sense to the original poster.

Comment: You are making a terrible mistake. No one knows what is $f(1)$ or even whether $f(1)$ exists or not? Moreover as my answer shows there is no need to know whether $f(1)$ exists or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27563/discussion-between-zenohm-and-paramanand-singh).

Answer (score 0):

By illegal calculations, we get $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x) = 4$. To prove that now, use the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limits, with $\delta = \epsilon/10$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the algebra of limits to get $$\lim_{x \to 1}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1}f(x) - 4 + 4 = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{f(x) - 4}{x - 1}\cdot (x - 1) + 4 = 10\cdot 0 + 4 = 4$$